# Exposing data from spring, hibernate application as restful

Tags: json, spring, hibernate

The work has been derived from this link 
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/spring-mvc-hibernate-maven-crud-operations-example.html. I have tried made an attempt of releasing the data of the application in a json format for which I have made further modifications in controller class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/team")
public class TeamController {

@Autowired
private TeamService teamService;

@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addTeamPage() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("add-team-form");
    modelAndView.addObject("team", new Team());
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addingTeam(@ModelAttribute Team team) {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");
    teamService.addTeam(team);

    String message = "Team was successfully added.";
    modelAndView.addObject("message", message);

    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/list")
public ModelAndView listOfTeams() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("list-of-teams");

    List<Team> teams = teamService.getTeams();
    modelAndView.addObject("teams", teams);

    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editTeamPage(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("edit-team-form");
    Team team = teamService.getTeam(id);
    modelAndView.addObject("team",team);
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView edditingTeam(@ModelAttribute Team team, @PathVariable Integer id) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");
    teamService.updateTeam(team);
    String message = "Team was successfully edited.";
    modelAndView.addObject("message", message);
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/delete/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deleteTeam(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");
    teamService.deleteTeam(id);
    String message = "Team was successfully deleted.";
    modelAndView.addObject("message", message);
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/team", method = RequestMethod.GET)
//    public @ResponseBody String listUsersJson (ModelMap model) throws JSONException {
    public @ResponseBody
    String listTeamJson () throws JSONException {
        JSONArray userArray = new JSONArray();
        for (Team team : teamService.getTeams()) {
            JSONObject userJSON = new JSONObject();
            userJSON.put("id", team.getId());
            userJSON.put("Name", team.getName());
            userJSON.put("Rating", team.getRating());
            userArray.put(userJSON);
        }
        return userArray.toString();
    }

}
```

But This code is showing error 404. How can I implement my application in order to release the data in json format?

Comment: can you show us the code that calls "/team/api/team"

Answer (score 0):

Change your JSON code to following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/team", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<TEAMS_OBJECT_TYPE>listTeamJson () throws JSONException {

        return teamService.getTeams();
    }

}
```

NOTE: TEAMS_OBJECT_TYPE needs to be replaced by the type that teamService.getTeams() returns.

@ResponseBody will automatically convert it into JSON, so all you need to do is read it properly on client side.

Comment: replaced TEAMS_OBJECT TYPE with Team but didn't worked.I am trying to implement learning from this example [link](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Getting+Started+with+Spring+MVC,+Hibernate+and+JSON). Is it possible to implement this application the same way?

Comment: What does teamService.getTeams() return? also add in show your code from where you make the call to "/team/api/team"